# How to allow or deny IP with regex or Wildcard in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I want to allow/deny set of IPs in my Nginx

```
allow   192.168.1.75;
allow   192.168.1.76;
allow   192.168.2.25;
allow   192.168.2.30;
```

Can I do this something like this?

```
allow   192.168.*.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CIDR notation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#allow).

For example:

```
allow 192.168.0.0/16;
```